# SSIS Custom Adapters - Unsigned DLLs - GAC Problem

Tags: ssis, custom-component

I are referencing third party dlls and .net library dlls (which are unsigned) inside our custom components.

To be able to use my custom ssis component, I believe I have to GAC it. And it seems, it is also required that I GAC the third party and .net library dlls that are referenced.

This is where the problem is. I tried strong signing all the dlls using a signer software and gac'ed them.

But now the errors I'm getting are like this:

```
The type '<dotnet class>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly '<dll name>, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: "PublicKeyToken=null" indicates something is looking for an unsigned version of the assembly.